# Keras shape error when given input from the front end

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am trying to build a chatbot using keras and bag of words model. But when i am trying to input the answer from the front end , this is the error that i get :-

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 69 but received input with shape [None, 1]
```

Here is my code :-

```
model = tensorflow.keras.Sequential([
        tensorflow.keras.layers.Dense(8,input_shape=(len(training[0]), )),
        tensorflow.keras.layers.Dense(8),
        tensorflow.keras.layers.Dense(len(output[0]), activation = "softmax")
    ])
    model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="categorical_crossentropy", metrics="accuracy")
    model.summary()

try:
        tensorflow.keras.models.load_model('heya')
        print('Existing model loaded.')
    except:
        model.fit(training, output, epochs=1000, batch_size=8)
        model.save('heya')
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: what are the shapes of 'training' and 'output'?

Comment: training shape is (24, 69)
Output shape is (24,13)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define correctly the input and output shapes of your model

```
import tensorflow
import numpy as np

training = np.random.uniform(0,1, (24, 69))
output = np.random.randint(0,2, (24, 13))

model = tensorflow.keras.Sequential([
        tensorflow.keras.layers.Dense(8,input_shape=(training.shape[1], )),
        tensorflow.keras.layers.Dense(8),
        tensorflow.keras.layers.Dense(output.shape[1], activation = "softmax")
    ])

model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="categorical_crossentropy", metrics="accuracy")
model.fit(training, output, epochs=10, batch_size=8)
```

the input dimension is the number of features (69 in your case), while the output dim is equivalent to the number of classes (13 in your case)

Comment: I made the modification but I am still getting the same error..

Comment: I provided a dummy example, try to check it... the shapes of the data are the same as yours

Comment: Let me know if there are problems